# How can I edit VS Code settings so that the tabs of modified files are highlighted?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In Sublime, this was supported by changing

```
"highlight_modified_tabs": true,
```

under Preferences | Settings. How can I get this in Visual Studio Code?

Comment: I too would like to know how to do this

Answer (score 20):

Some ability to highlight the top border of a modified tab was added in v1.29, [highlight modified tabs](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_29#_highlight-modified-tabs).

```
workbench.editor.highlightModifiedTabs: true;
```

It is not much of a change though.

With these colorCustomizations in settings.json:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "tab.activeModifiedBorder": "#ff0000",
    "tab.inactiveModifiedBorder": "#ff0000",
    "tab.unfocusedActiveModifiedBorder": "#ff0000",
    "tab.unfocusedInactiveModifiedBorder": "#ff0000",
}
```

Comment: The settings file path is: `%APPDATA%\Code\User\settings.json` on Windows, 
`$HOME/Library/Application Support/Code/User/settings.json` on MacOS and `$HOME/.config/Code/User/settings.json` on Linux, as per the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settings-file-locations)

Comment: this is a rear (and of course correct) answer over the internet....many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well this isn't the best answer, but I ended up hacking one of vscode's core css files:

```
/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/electron-browser/workbench.main.css
```

I'm not sure where this file will exist on other platforms.

I put this css at the bottom of the file:

```
.tab.dirty .label-name {
    color: #ffcc66;
}
```

Restart VSCode after this. It will complain at you saying the install is corrupt... but just click ignore and don't notify me. I'm pretty frustrated that I couldn't find a better solution, but it works...

Comment: Any updates on this? Its kinda ok as a workaround, but I have to redo every time an autoupdate comes down. Can it go into a theme or something?