# VSCode: enable or disable editor tabs modified since last git commit, show git status with modified tabs colors

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

In VSCODE, how can I highlight tabs that were modified compared to previous git commit?  In order to show their git status.

Note: This is not a duplicate of [How can I edit VS Code settings so that the tabs of modified files are highlighted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39085107/how-can-i-edit-vs-code-settings-so-that-the-tabs-of-modified-files-are-highlight), since that question relates to unsaved changes, and this question relates to saved changes that were modified compared to the recent git commit.

Comment: you get a list of modified files in the SCM tab, why also need to color the tabs?

Comment: @rioV8 This would be useful because if you have many tabs open, it would allow you to easily see which ones are actively under development. This is currently a pain point for me at least.

Comment: I feel your pain!!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

v1.53 has added this functionality, see [Release notes: tab decorations](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_53.md#tab-decorations).

> Two new settings allow you to configure whether editor tabs show
> decorations, such as git status or diagnostics. Use
> `workbench.editor.decorations.colors` to decorate tabs with colors, like
> red/green for files with errors and warnings, and use
> `workbench.editor.decorations.badges` to decorate tabs with badges, like
> `M` for git modified.

Previously : [These are not enabled by default.]

**Edit : Note that these are scheduled to be turned on by default as of v1.55.**  so if you want to turn this feature off, disable

`workbench.editor.decorations.colors`
`workbench.editor.decorations.badges`

or these settings in the UI

`Workbench > Editor > Decorations: Colors`
`Workbench > Editor > Decorations: Badges`

[image: tab decorations demo]

The `colorCustomizations` `gitDecoration....`

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {

    "gitDecoration.modifiedResourceForeground": "#ff0000",
}
```

work to change BOTH the Explorer view and tab colors.

Comment: This is awesome

Comment: Note: they might be enabled by default with 1.55: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/7b2899cd4b82aac739642ee3be619f877f3d5940/release-notes/v1_55.md#tab-decoration-on-by-default

Comment: Great thanks for this. It got automatically enabled for me

Comment: you can also try this to disable it git.decorations.enabled": false,

Comment: @Bhumit070 The trouble with `"git.decorations.enabled":false` is that it also disables the decorations from the Explorer as well as the tabs.  I like them in the Explorer files but not in the tabs for most themes.