# VSCode - tab icon color reflect git status

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I really like that VSCode colors the file name in the sidebar depending on the git status (green for new, yellowish for modified). What I don't like is the file names for the tabs don't also reflect that. Is there a way to make the tabs use the same colors as the sidebar? Additionally, are the colors configurable for the different git states?

[image]

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/65998050/836330 this functionality is being added to v1.53.  Pretty much a duplicate.

Answer (score 6):

Dec 2020: This is not likely, because there are a lot of issues/plugins already around tabs colors for VSCode (like [issues/31308](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/31308#issuecomment-470747503))

That means any *text* color you might want would likely clash (be less readable) with the foreground/background tab colors imposed by a setting or a plugin (like [ColorTabs](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=orepor.color-tabs-vscode-ext)).

That is why custom *text* colors are better represented in the sidebar rather than the tabs themselves.

---

Update VSCode 1.53 Jan. 2021: as described with [Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/836330/mark)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65998050/6309), this is implemented in term of tab decoration:

> ### [Tab decorations](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/cd717bb4195d40ae8f556679348d38d6dce4321a/release-notes/v1_53.md#tab-decorations)
>
> Two new settings allow you to configure whether editor tabs show decorations, such as `git status` or diagnostics.
>
> - Use `workbench.editor.decorations.colors` to decorate tabs with colors, like red/green for files with errors and warnings, and
> - use `workbench.editor.decorations.badges` to decorate tabs with badges, like M for git modified.
>
> [image: Editor Tab with decorations]