# VSCode Tabs: How to disable tab highlighting for linting errors and git changes

Tags: visual-studio-code, interface, highlight

I've updated VSCode to 1.62 and now my tabs are highlighted when there are linting errors or they are untracked/modified by git: [Tab image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQCOu.png)

How to disable it in settings?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/65998050/836330