# VSCode `workbench.colorCustomizations` for modified tab foreground

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, formatting, customization

In the screenshot below, I modify foreground color across standard `tab` attributes, as well as `gitDecoration`, but the foreground color of both a 'dirty' tab and corresponding workspace folder are the standard yellow. Is there an attribute I'm overlooking?

The same yellow is present even if it set `workbench.editor.highlightModifiedTabs` to `true` or when disabling all extensions. Notably, on relaunch, I initially see my `gitDecoration` color, but yellow appears later.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43600820/17252895) suggests modifying the underlying CSS... and resetting after updates. Is that the only solve?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a folder-level `settings.json` modifying my user-level version shown here. Deleting the folder-level fixed the issue.